# Android deeplink path / pathPatern

Tags: android, url, uri, deep-linking

If my URL looks something like this
https://somesite.com//#/?token=H41SB9SN

What pathPatern or path should I use in AndroidManifest, so that when user clicks such a link, my app will will open?

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
          <data android:scheme="https"
          android:host="somesite.com"
          android:pathPattern="/#/?token=" />
```